# How do you find the area under a curve only for the area above the x-axis?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

Let's say I have function $f(x) = -x^2 + 1$ and I want to find the area between that curve and the $x$-axis

I use definite integrals obviously.

Let's say I use the $-3$ and $3$ as my definite values for my integral, meaning I would be looking at both areas under and over the $x$-axis

Besides changing my definite values, is there any way to have my integral only measure the area above the $x$-axis?

Comment: Find the zeroes of $f$, maybe?

Comment: Just found the area where the function is above the $x$-axis and then evaluate the integral inside that interval.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the area of the following set:

$$S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x \in [-1,1], 0 \le y \le 1-x^2\}.$$

The area of $S$ is given by

$$ \int_{-1}^1(1-x^2) dx.$$